# SVG - Changing gradient to solid fill with average color value

Tags: python, svg, gradient

I am trying to change the gradients(linear,radial etc) in an svg file to the average solid fill. I am quite new in dealing with svg's. Also this should be done by a script as I have so many svg files. I have been looking for this on the internet for last 3 hours and found nothing at all.

I am able to parse svg in the python xml structure and able to access its complete structure. But dont know how to calculate the average color value or anything about it? Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

**Edit :** Here is the code which will remove all the defs tags in the svg. Since defs tags contain gradient tags, it will remove all the gradients. But I want them to change to an average solid color.

```
import os
from xml.dom import minidom

for f in os.listdir():
    if f.endswith(".svg"):
        doc = minidom.parse(f)
        for defstag in doc.getElementsByTagName('defs'):
            defstag.parentNode.removeChild(defstag)

        f = open(f,'w')
        f.write(doc.documentElement.toxml())
        f.close()
        doc.unlink()
```

Comment: My first question and someone downvoted it

Comment: I have asked the question according to guidelines...I have searched for the problem and I cant find the solution

Comment: Show some code that you have tried.  Be more specific and you will probably get a better response.

Comment: Okay, I have edited the question and put in the code I wrote

Comment: What's an average colour and how are you planning to calculate it?

Comment: Actually that doesnt matter. I just want a solid fill color in the region. Also it doesnt mean it can be anything. Say a linear gradient is from red to white, so solid fill can be light red. Like that.

Comment: Search through the file for fill="url(someGradient)" and change it to fill="colour". Alternatively delete all the gradient stops so that each gradient has a single stop of the colour you want.

Answer (score 0):

I did a very basic approach with Python:

1. Search for linear gradients within a svg file using the built-in xml.etree.ElementTree library using findall() with XPath expressions.
2. Extract a solid color by selecting the first attribute "stop-color".
3. Extract the "id" attribute to search the tree where the corresponding gradient was used.
4. Search the tree and overwrite the attribute "fill" by the previously obtained solid-color.

(Currently, it only searches for linear gradients and does only take the first color from it as a template. The script could be extendend by other gradient types and a method that extracts multiple colors to build an average color as template.)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

# Remove gradients from svg file and replace them by solid color
# First open the svg file to be modified
tree = ET.parse("Graphs-Screenshot.svg")
root = tree.getroot()

# Search for the linearGradient tag within the svg file
for descendant in root.findall("{*}defs/{*}linearGradient"):
    print(descendant)
    id = descendant.get("id")
    print("id: " + id)

    # Extract the (first) color of the gradient as template
    # for solid color fill.
    # Might be extended to extract average of multiple colors
    color = descendant[0].get("stop-color")
    print("color: " + color)
    print("{*}g/{*}"+id)

    # Replace all gradients with previously extracted solid color
    for gradient in root.iterfind("{*}g/"):
        if gradient.get("fill") == ("url(#"+id+")"):
            print("old gradient:", gradient.get("fill"))
            gradient.set("fill", color)
            print("new solid color:", gradient.get("fill"))
    
# Save the edited svg file
tree.write("newSVG.svg", encoding="UTF-8")

# Convert svg to reportlab own rlg format
rlg = svg2rlg("newSVG.svg")
# Save a PDF out of rlg file
renderPDF.drawToFile(rlg, "Graphs-Screenshot.pdf")
```

Code can also be found here: https://github.com/DrakeGladiator/SVGGradientRemover